# Using R to loop through downloading of files and renaming it

Tags: r, excel, loops, download

I would like to download multiple files from a list of urls. Some of the urls may be invalid and I would like to skip it if there is error.
If possible, would also like to rename the downloaded file based on the ID.

Appreciate if someone could help me out. A sample of my data is as follow:

```
ID <- c('L18491','K18781','I28004')
url <- c('https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLSX_50.xlsx',
         'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLSX_101.xlsx',
         'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLSX_100.xlsx')


df <- data.frame(ID, url)
```

Comment: When you say rename, is it the columns to rename or create the objects with that ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `possibly` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)    
out_lst <- map(df$url, pfun)
names(out_lst) <- df$ID
```

where

```
pfun <- possibly(f1, otherwise = NA)
```

where

```
f1 <- function(urllink) {
      openxlsx::read.xlsx(urllink)
 }
```

---

Or another option is `tryCatch`

```
f2 <-  function(urllink) {

      tryCatch(openxlsx::read.xlsx(urllink), 
             error = function(e) message("error occured"))
}
out_lst2 <- lapply(df$url, f2)
```

---

If we want to use `download.file`

```
lapply(seq_along(df$url), function(i)
        tryCatch(download.file(df$url[i], paste0(getwd(), "/", df$ID[i], ".xlsx")),
              error = function(e) message("error occured")))
```

Or using `iwalk`

```
library(tibble)
pfun2 <- possibly(download.file, otherwise = NA)
iwalk(deframe(df), ~ pfun2(.x, as.character(glue::glue('{getwd()}/{.y}.xlsx'))))
```

Comment: how to download the files into the wd?

Comment: @Jane Updated the post with `download.file`

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't download the xlsx files into my specified folder.

Comment: @Jane For that you need to specify the 'wd' `paste`ed before the df$ID[i] i..e `paste0(getwd(), df$ID[i], ".xlsx")`

Comment: thanks, but i did notice in the destination folder, there were files appearing and then disappearing. have checked, there is no dup in the file names. any idea why?

Comment: @Jane. Did you meant that the files created are getting deleted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `download.file` to download the file and name it according to `ID` variable.

```
Map(function(x, y) tryCatch(download.file(x, sprintf('%s.xlsx', y)), 
                            error = function(e) {}, 
                            warning = function(w) {}), df$url, df$ID)
```

This will download the files in your working directory and name it as `ID.xlsx`. Also it will skip any error or warnings generated.